# Problems with python 2.4 and 2.4.4 in struct.unpack and win/lin

Tags: python, windows, linux, 32bit-64bit, python-2.x

i'm coding on a Linux debian machine with python 2.4.

My neighbour with Windows XP and python 2.4.4

He can run this code:

```
w1, w2, w3 = unpack("LLL", pack("LLHH", localtime, ipddr, counter, aid))
```

But when i try this code i become this error:

```
w1, w2, w3 = unpack("LLL", pack("LLHH", localtime, ipddr, counter, aid))
struct.error: unpack str size does not match format
```

Can it be the Version of python or maybe the system?

Comment: Nice with I it is js just working ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `I` format code instead of `L`.

On your Linux machine, `L` isn't twice as long as `H`, it's four times as long -- 8 bytes (64 bits) instead of 4 bytes (32 bits).

`I` should be 4 bytes (32 bits) on both.

**Edit:** Make sure to read eryksun's comment.